# Which loss function is suitable?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am using PyTorch and am still quite new to the library.

I have a relation between my input and output given by `y = ax + b`, where `a` and `b` are sampled from some distribution (say Uniform), that is, they are random. I would like to train a network to predict `x` upon seeing `y` and `a`. I am employing a network, named `probability_network`, with `nn.Linear` layers. There are `N` (say 10) classes to choose from for `x`.

```
class ProabilityNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ProabilityNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(8, 76)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(76, 150)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(150, 75)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(75, 14)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(14, 10)
        self.tanh = nn.Tanh()
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        return self.softmax(self.fc5(self.fc4(self.relu(self.fc3(self.relu(self.fc2(self.relu(self.fc1(inputs)))))))))

probabilty_network = ProbabilityNetwork()
```

Upon seeing `y`, the loss function should help the network predict an `x` that minimizes `||y-ax||^2`. All the quantities in `y = ax + b` are vectors (each of length 4, in this example). I have already tried the following loss function.

```
prob_values = probabilty_network(torch.cat([y, a], dim=0))  # shape: (batch_size, 10)
x_hat = mapping_tensor[torch.argmax(prob_values, dim=1)]  # Mapping from probability to one of 10 classes, mapping_tensor is an array of shape (10, 4)

mse_loss = nn.MSELoss()
loss = mse_loss(y, a*x_hat)
```

As an example, the `mapping_tensor` could contain binary representation of values from `0` (`0000`) to `9` (`1001`). The reason I need the binary representation of the class is that I need a vector `x` for the loss `||y-ax||^2`. In this case, `x` is a `4` length vector whereas the output of the neural network is a `10`  length vector.

The above setup doesn't work. Half the values in the predicted class (written out in binary) are always wrong, implying the network is confused while training.

Further, this is not an unachievable problem. Solution to the above mentioned loss function exists (with errors, of course, but the errors are far lesser than 50%) but is computationally intensive. I am trying to check if the network can somehow learn to predict at lower complexity. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Furthermore, from an optimization standpoint, the loss function is the best possible solution (that I know of). So, changing the loss function would only lead to poorer results.

Another way to look at the problem is as follows. Suppose the network sees `y` and `a`. The network then computes `|y-ax|` for each class `x` (out of 10 possible classes), and then chooses the class with least value of the computed value. And my question is, what loss function can I use to make the network train in this fashion?

Comment: You lost me at `mapping_tensor`. Up until that point this looked like a least squares regression problem. Based on the problem statement you gave earlier it's not clear to me what the purpose of mapping is, nor what binary representations have to do with anything.

Comment: @jodag I am sorry for being vague. The network should be predicting a class. The class has a representation in binary. From the argmax of the probability vector given by the network, I find this class representation and then use this representation in the loss function. The loss function expects a vector and probability vector can't be fed in. Is this clear?

Answer (score 0):

I answer based on this statement:

> I would like to train a network to predict `x` upon seeing `y`.

where `y = ax + b`, with `a` and `b` random vectors (multiplicative and additive noise).

You can train your model in a supervised manner. Given `y`, your model predicts `x_pred`. Then the loss function is defined as the euclidean distance between your prediction `x_pred` and the ground truth `x`:

```
loss = torch.nn.functional.mse_loss(x_pred, x)
```

Comment: Thank you. Neb, if you look closely, `||y-ax||^2` is not same as the loss in your answer. This works but the performance is not at par with the solution to the loss function that I mentioned in my question. I am not in a position to change the loss function, because that is the best thing to do in this scenario.

Comment: The reason could be that the decisions boundaries that are learnt by the network are based off of `y`, whereas I would like the decision boundaries be based off of `|y-ax|` for `10` classes of `x`.

Comment: I have slightly modified the problem, please have a look.

Comment: Can you please point to the computationally expensive solution? I am very curious. Even few hints are appreciated.

Comment: it is simple actually, for each `y` and `a` received, compute, `N` (in this case 10) Euclidean distances between `y` and `ax`, where `x` comes from each of the `N` classes. The decision is then the `x` corresponding to the least Euclidean distance. So, for 1000 `y` vectors, one needs to compute `N`*1000 number of Euclidean distances, which is extremely slow and computation intensive.

Comment: I am still confused. if `y = ax + b`, then once you compute `||y-ax||` what you get is exactly `||b||`, that is the L2 norm of a random vector. Now, since such random vector is the same for all classes, I do not understand how, selecting a class for `x` would minimize `||y-ax|| = ||b||`. In other words, I do not see a solution to your problem. You cannot minimize such distance because you have no control over `b`.

Comment: `||y-ax|| = ||b||`, only when `x` is the correct solution. For any other `x`, `||y-ax|| > ||b||`. So my solution is still valid as long as the network learns to predict the correct `x` and that minimizes the loss function.